# selenium webdriver takes very long when not finding an element in firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox, xpath, webdriver

I am using selenium webdriver to locate element in firefox/win10.
The webpage is the following.

https://24h.pchome.com.tw/

There is an iframe tag in the html source document whose element can be accessed with the following two xpaths.

```
"//iframe[@src='https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TKSM5PF']"

'//html/body/noscript[1]/iframe[1]'
```

Then I used the following the python statement to locate the element once for each of the above xpaths.

```
e = WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xPath)))
```

The situation is that when a tag can be located, webdriver will return the element quickly.  But for the above-mentioned element, somehow webdriver could not locate it and takes like 5 mins to return.
As you can see, the waiting time for the location is set to 1 second.  But in fact, it takes like 5 mins.

I will appreciate it very much if someone can tell me how to make webdriver returns quickly when locating an element fails.

Thanks!

Farn

Comment: Did you use `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);` by any chance? anywhere in you code.

Comment: No!  I though 1 means 1 second in my webdriverwait statement.

Comment: Yes, but only when implicit wait is set to 0. Otherwise they are mixed to unexpected result.

Comment: Thanks!  But when I tried your command, the console said that webdriver does not have attribute 'manage'.  Was there something that I missed ?

Comment: This is Java code, in Python it's `driver.implicitly_wait(300)`. I wasn't suggesting you use it, I was asking if you are already using it, it might be the source of this behavior. It doesn't have to be right before the `WebDriverWait`, it can be anywhere in your code.

Comment: Hi, dear Guy: Thanks for your helpful advice.  Yes, you are very correct.  I inherited the code from my students and then found that they indeed used this implicitly_wait() statement.  Now the problem is solved.  Thank you very much.  Then do you know when this iframe is not located, does it mean that the iframe is not visible or enabled ?

Comment: You used `visibility_of_element_located`, which means the `iframe` wasn't visible or couldn't be located at all. It took the full time of the implicit wait, so I suspect the later. By the way, you can use `frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` for frames.

Comment: Looking at the site this `iframe` you are looking for is not realy an `iframe`, just a place holder in case JavaScript is disabled, and it doesn't contain anything in it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the stupid question.  As Guy suggested, this is because that the webdriverwait.until statement interfered with the implicitly_wait() statement declared somewhere else. After changing the implicitly_wait statement, the problem is gone.